# Rails - Run system command in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to run a C++ executable in my Rails app that is place in a folder called "algo", like this:

```
result = `cd algo && ./my_main #{str} -1 -1 #{id}`
```

In development works flawlessly but in production in the cloud does not run

Consider that:

1) In the cloud, that is a virtual machine, i run the same executable without problems in the console terminal navigate through the Rails application folders, it only fails when i try to run it from the Rails application

2)

```
 Rails.logger.info result
```

Returns nothing

3)

```
 Rails.logger.info `pwd`
```

Does return the current folder of the proyect

4)

```
Rails.logger.info $?
```

Only returns: pid 35314 exit 127

5)

```
  Rails.logger.info File.exist?("algo/my_main")
```

Returns `true`

6)
In the `config/environments/production.rb` the log level is `config.log_level = :info`

7)
In the `log/production.log` does not appear any error like you will see in development in the terminal

8)
I also try to use other commands like: `system()`, `exec()`, `%x()` with the same result

9)
Finally, i run `sudo chmod -R 777` in the virtual machine, in the main folder before the Rails folder app, i think that is implicit in the point 1, but for clarify

Comment: Try using the full path `cd /folder/anotherone/algo`

Comment: Invoke your command from a absolute path instead of relying on `cwd`. The working directory in your script is not guaranteed to be the same as what you had in the terminal. You can get the `pwd` in ruby with `Dir.pwd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always use absolute paths for any code that will be executed by a script. The `PATH` variable may be different for the user executing the script than it is for the user that you use, and its much better to be 100% precise about the file path you want than to rely on `PATH`.

Along the same lines, make sure the user that runs the Rails server have execute permissions on the script. If in doubt, login as that user and attempt to execute the script.

You also need to escape both `str` and `id` for security reasons. Even if these variables are not *currently* derived in any way from submitted parameters, there's always a possibility that whatever function contains this code might be executed with user-submitted variables at some point. Basically, its better to be safe than sorry, because this is the kind of security hole that could allow anyone on the Internet to execute arbitrary code on your server.